# Laravel 3.2.13 Upload File

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I'm trying to upload files not from Form but from directory, say the given directory is "D:\Pictures".

```
$directory = "D:\Pictures";
```

How to retrieve the files stored in that folder and then upload to my web application?

I'm using old laravel here, version : 3.2.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you CAN'T. Upload the file not from Form but from directory is an dangerous action. Simply imaging that hackers could create a simple website for submit something and easy to stolen your file easily.

So, reconsider about your goal. Why you have to upload a file from client computer without select from form?

Comment: I'm about to create import data functionality, the import file is *.xlsx and have **posts** records in it. Every **post** got an image, so it's basically impossible if I put the image in that template and import it to my database.

Comment: So I put the **image directory** column in that template.

Comment: You mean, you want to import images from a specific folder in client automatically? In your template xlsx, column "Images", you could write the name of image. And when uploads, upload xlsx and all images at the same time. You could use javascript multi-upload, handle and validate with laravel

Comment: Yes, if I change the image directory to "D:\Posts_Pictures" in my xlsx template then it will automatically upload images found on "D:\Post_Pictures" to server when I run import.